# Is there tag styling in react js inline style

Tags: html, css, reactjs

For example, there is react js code,

```
<p> hello </p>
<p> world </p>
```

In here, i want change font size with inline style.
I know this can be resolved to

```
<p style={{fontSize: '24px',}}> hello</p>
<p style={{fontSize: '24px',}}> world</p>
```

But i want to know about how to change all

tag to one const styling

Comment: You can create a state object `this.state={style: {{fontSize: '24px'}}}` and pass it wherever you want

Comment: You could use `const` of course but it doesn't seem like a good approach in the long run. Try to looks for something like `styled components` library or CSS as well

Comment: [W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp) has some good examples regarding styling React components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fontStyles = {
     fontSize:"24px"
}
```

Add the styled object to your p tag.

```
<p style={fontStyles}> hello </p>
<p style={fontStyles}> world </p>
```

You can use Styled components. It's recommended in React and good best practices Check the Docs
https://styled-components.com/

Using Styled Components

```
const MyStyledParagraph = styled.p`
     font-size : 24px
`
```

Best this if you export the MyStyledParagraph Component you can use anywhere in the project. Styled Component use CSS styled syntax. (fontSize is use as font-size, like in CSS)

```
<MyStyledParagraph>Hello</MyStyledParagraph>
<MyStyledParagraph>World</MyStyledParagraph>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can try something like this:

```
const mystyle = {
  fontSize: '24px'
}
```

and use it like:

```
<p style={mystyle}>Hello</p>
<p style={mystyle}>World</p>
```

[Reference](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

[Working example](https://www.w3schools.com/react/showreact.asp?filename=demo2_react_css_inline_object)

Example code:

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const mystyle = {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",
      padding: "10px",
      fontFamily: "Arial"
    };
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={mystyle}>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const paragraphStyle = {
 fontSize: '24px'
}
```

Then apply it

```
<p style={paragraphStyle}> hello</p>
<p style={paragraphStyle}> world</p>
```